# Get exactly 1 day using NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How i can get exactly 1 day using NSDate i.e from **2014-08-01 00:00:00 +0000** to **2014-08-01 23:59:59 +0000**. Is this possible to get this using NSDate?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clearly understand your question. If you want to get next day for `NSDate`:

```
+ (NSDate *)numberOfDays:(NSInteger)numberOfDays from:(NSDate *)fromDate {
    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.day = numberOfDays;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:fromDate options:0];
}
```

If you want to compare if two `NSDate` are in the same day, then (from NSDate category):

```
- (BOOL)isOnTheSameDayAs:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components1 = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit) fromDate:self];
    NSDateComponents *components2 = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    return ((components1.year == components2.year) &&
            (components1.month == components2.month) &&
            (components1.day == components2.day));
}
```